# Python convert a string to lowercase except some special strings

Tags: python, string, lowercase

I'd like to convert a string to lowercase but if this string contains one of the special words it should leave as is.

```
specialwords = ['Special1', 'Special']
```

Let's say our input string is like this:

```
Ali is really Special.
```

Output should be like this:

```
ali is really Special
```

Here is the code I've used so far.

```
def makeUrl(inputString):
    list =  {"ı": "i",
             "I": "ı",
             "İ": "İ",
             "î": "i",
             "Ç": "c",
             "ç": "c",
             " ": "-",
             "ş": "s",
             "Ş": "s",
             "Ğ": "g",
             "ğ": "g",
             "Ü": "u",
             "ü": "u",
             "Ö": "o",
             "ö": "o",
             "!": "",
             "?": "",
             "'": "",
             "“": "",
             "”": "",
             "â": "a"}

    inputString = inputString.encode('utf8', 'replace')

    for letter in list:
        inputString = inputString.replace(letter, liste[letter])
    if "Ali" in inputString:
        return inputString
    else:
        return inputString.lower()
```

Comment: I check whether the special word is in the string that I'd like to convert. Like this: ` if 'Special' in inputString: return inputString`

Comment: Please post the code you've tried into the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
specialwords = ['Special1', 'Special']
string = "Ali is really Special"

toLower = lambda x: " ".join( a if a in specialwords else a.lower()
            for a in x.split() )

print (toLower(string))
# ali is really Special
```

In case of any punctuations in the `string`, you can easily strip them off with a simple `lambda`:

```
from string import punctuation
p_strip = lambda x: "".join(w for w in x if w not in punctuation)

string = "Ali is really Special."

# Now `toLower` function should look something like this:
toLower = lambda x: " ".join( a if p_strip(a) in specialwords else a.lower()
    for a in x.split() )
```

Comment: if use string = "Ali is really Special."

Comment: well in that case you gotta strip off the punctuations then.

Comment: if is needed preserve the blank spaces

Comment: If we use string = `What is so Special.about Ali is really Special.`